# How to write modules that are both nodejs compatible and browser compatible?

Tags: node.js

I am writing a node module {collection of modules}and in future this might be ported to browser environments too.
For that reason I am looking for programming techniques that will allow me to write code once and then reuse the same, may be if it requires some kind of running build , its fine.

Its fine if this is the workflow,

- write node modules
- run some build script that converts above written code into a single js file to be able to run in browser enviroments

Please do not suggest me browserify.

Why no browserfiy or any other similar stuff? 
I saw the code that was generated . It was huge and had lot of browserify introduced code.
I found it difficult to troubleshoot and go through the code i have written

Comment: `Please do not suggest me browserify.` O_O because you said that part, I just discovered browserify. Wow, what a neat library! Thank you!

Comment: About that do not suggest clause, it would make much more sense if you added why do not want it suggested. Not only does it help us understand why you don't want browserify, it may also make cleare what you do want.

Comment: similar question, with workable answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7337518/edit

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend giving another look at Browserify. Other than that, add a [Universal Module Definition](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) (UMDJS) exporter in your files. This will allow you to expose your modules in node, browserify, requirejs/amd, or just thrown into a script tag on any site.

Can also use a module transpiler -- write in [a ES6 module exporter](https://github.com/square/es6-module-transpiler), and have it convert for use in a browser, or a commonjs/node environment.

Answer (score 0):

Well, [Darren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2604071/darren-white), let's consider I have some `Agent` object which would require `XMLHttpRequest` for its transport layer browser-side but use NodeJS' `http` API server-side.

Where do you make the switch using Grunt for example? Let's say we've got the following files: `Agent.js`, `transport-browser.js` and `transport-node.js`. Maybe I'm off on your technique but it is something like I would go for (I'm currently thinking about all that).